# Numerical integration with singularities in python (principal value)

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to integrate a function with singularities  using the quad function in `scipy.integrate` but I'm not getting the desired answer. Here is the code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
def fun(x):
    return 1./(1-x**2)
quad(fun, -2, 2, points=[-1, 1])
```

This results in IntegrationWarning and return value about `0.4`.

The poles for the function are [-1,1]. The answer should be of roughly 1.09 (calculated using pen and paper).

Comment: Interestingly, `2*quad(fun, 0, 2, points=[1])[0])` gives correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `weight='cauchy'` can be used to efficiently compute the principal value of divergent integrals like this one. It means that the function provided to `quad` will be implicitly multiplied by `1/(x-wvar)`, so adjust that function accordingly (multiply it by `x-wvar` where wvar is the point of singularity).

```
i1 = quad(lambda x: -1./(x+1), 0, 2, weight='cauchy', wvar=1)[0]
i2 = quad(lambda x: -1./(x-1), -2, 0, weight='cauchy', wvar=-1)[0]
result = i1 + i2
```

The result is `1.0986122886681091`.

With a simple function like this, you can also do symbolic integration with SymPy:

```
from sympy import symbols, integrate
x = symbols('x')
f = integrate(1/(1-x**2), x)
result = (f.subs(x, 2) - f.subs(x, -2)).evalf()
```

Result: `1.09861228866811`. Without `evalf()` it would be `log(3)`.

Comment: I think you meant to say "divergent integra**nds**" instead of _"divergent integra**ls**"_.

Comment: Also, since the integrand is an even function, it is even necessary to compute `i2`? It should be equal to `i1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: In this specific example, no. In general, one has to split the integral as shown because the Cauchy weight provides only one singularity. And I do mean "integrals"

Comment: With regard to splitting integral in two: since integrand is an even function, it is symmetrical with regard to the Y-axis. This means that you can integrate only over the `[0,2]` range - `i1` and set the integral over the `[-2,0]` range - `i2` - equal to `i1`. That is, you can do `result = 2 * i1` instead of computing two integrals as it is done now.

Comment: suppose if I want a weight of 1/(x-wvar)**2 how should I approach?

Comment: @Murali These are not among the supported weights. An integral with such a factor probably diverges.

Comment: Thanks, @WelcometoStackOverflow. Is there a way to compute integrals where you cant factorize, I mean it's not a polynomial.

Comment: @Murali One can include the factor into the integrand, for example integration of sin(1/(x-2)) could be done by integrating (x-2)*sin(1/(x-2)) with the Cauchy weight. Also, the other answer suggests a reasonable approach with removing the epsilon-neighborhood of the pole to improve convergence.

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't get it to work with the original function. I came up with this to evaluate the principal value in scipy:

```
def principal_value(func, a, b, poles, eps=10**(-6)):
    #edges
    res = quad(func,a,poles[0]-eps)[0]+quad(func,poles[-1]+eps,b)[0]
    #inner part
    for i in range(len(poles)-1):
        res += quad(func, poles[i]+eps, poles[i+1]-eps)[0]
    return res
```

Where `func` is your function handle, `a` and `b` are the limits, `poles` is a list of poles and `eps` is how near you want to approach the poles. You can make eps smaller and smaller to get a better result, but maybe sympy will be better for a problem like this.

With this function and the standard `eps` I get `1.0986112886023367` as a result, which is almost the same as wolframalpha gives.